# Where can i store a Json for Roku to Parse?

Tags: json, parsing, github, roku

With the closure of MyJson.com, where can a developer upload a json file to be parsed? I have completed my file with Json Feed Manager and uploaded the file to GitHub, but the ability to read to use the URL as a raw does not work any longer. I'm thinking this was turned into a paid feature vs. free. Some of the other Roku developers have hinted the best suggestion is to acquire a paid webhost and make a directory for json to be uploaded into it and point the Direct Publisher to the source.

https://community.roku.com/t5/Roku-Direct-Publisher/bd-p/roku-direct-publisher

Answer (score 0):

> I have completed my file with Json Feed Manager and uploaded the file to GitHub, but the ability to read to use the URL as a raw does not work any longer.

I don't believe this is the case. You can still access raw content from GitHub through the domain https://raw.githubusercontent.com

Template:

```
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/<username>/<repository>/<branch>/<path-to-file>
```

Example:

```
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pomber/covid19/master/package.json
```

Comment: Ok you are right the raw command works, but I think I'm missing an API code embedded into my header. When Roku pulls the feed it's indicating we expected an xml or json instead we see texts.

Comment: @JohnHilla - I don't know what you mean, if you are hosting a json file, the response will always be a json. What you are referencing about headers, applies to APIs that support dynamic responses where the service can decide the output based on the header you are passing; headers shouldn't have anything to do in this case. Can you expand on what you mean by _"instead we see texts"_? because a json file is text.